# How do I force a go subprocess to load a plugin?

Tags: go, plugins

I'd like to write a small Go program that monitors another Go program, reporting periodic telemetry about it. However, I want to do this without requiring the monitored program to include the monitoring code, or to explicitly load the monitoring code.

So for example, given the following amazing server program:

server.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("ping")
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

And the following awesome monitoring code, built as a plugin:

monitor.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func init() {
    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Println("doing monitoring stuff...")
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()
}
```

I want to launch the server binary via an `exec` call or whatever, force the server's process to load `monitor.so` as a plugin (which runs the monitor's `init()` function), after which the server carries on doing what it would normally do as if nothing had happened.

The end result would be that `server` is still doing its regular ping thing, but there's also a running goroutine doing the monitoring when launched via my little program. The server didn't need to know about monitor at all when it was being built from source (i.e. I wouldn't need to rebuild the server binary to add this functionality).

My questions are:

1. How would I do this in Go (so that I can run it in a debug env at the very least, even if it's a little flaky)?
2. How would I do this **SAFELY** in Go (so that I can run it in a production env without launching all nukes)?

Comment: What is the reason for the "without requiring the monitored program to include the monitoring code" requirement?

Comment: Because I want this to be a standalone program + so plugin that doesn't require a rebuild of the binary-to-be-monitored (so that I can check already deployed apps).

Comment: You're saying `I wouldn't need to rebuild the server binary to add this functionality` which implies you're just using the binary as-is. That leaves you with running a completely separate process on its own. It's just another job running on your machine, how you do that depends on your orchestration.

Comment: I'm talking about making a Go executable `monitor`, with which I can monitor a Go executable `server` by calling `./monitor -exepath=./server`. `monitor` forks and launches (or execs or whatever) `server`, injects code into it to load the `monitor.so` plugin, whose `init()` function starts a monitoring goroutine. Then the server continues running and doing its thing, while the monitoring goroutine monitors it from the inside and reports from time to time.

Comment: What kinds of things do you hope to monitor here? Any meaningful monitoring I can think of, other than just a ping to see if the process is up, will require a lot more than loading a plugin. In other words, you'll have to re-compile with monitoring support anyway. All that can go in a plugin is the communication protocol to talk to the other process.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I want to monitor. There are tons of things that you can only activate/see from within a process. Once the plugin loads and executes, you're only limited by what code you've put in the plugin. My question is **HOW** to do it, not **WHETHER** I should do it. Comments to the latter are off-topic.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem. Asking about why you're doing something that seems off is almost always on-topic, when it comes to helping solve the problem.

Comment: "There are tons of things that you can only activate/see from within a process" Yes, no doubt. But the vast majority of these things are so lightweight to monitor, that there's no reason to bother with the overhead and complexity of plugins. Just add 2kb to your executable. The other things that are interesting, which would add enough overhead not to want to re-compile, probably require instrumentation to be present throughout the code, making a plugin worthless.

Comment: Ugh this is why SO can be so infuriating. If anyone knowledgeable about Go's internals would like to chime in, I'm hoping to build something along similar lines to SystemTap https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/07/24/probing-golang-runtime-using-systemtap but obviously MUCH more simple (as in: launch a Go app, force it to load a plugin, end of story).

Comment: Actually what Flimzy wrote is handy. It tells even they didn't find any workaround other than modifying the standard lib, which must be used to build the app (not the original standard lib).

Comment: Actually, what Flimzy wrote is wrong. SystemTap doesn't modify the standard lib. Everything is done at runtime, with no modification to any files required. That's the whole point. PTrace exists for runtime monitoring and modification. I only want to know the best way to use the Go interface to ptrace or whatever other low-level API, for the purpose of injecting code, and how to do it as safely as possible.

Comment: Oh I see now. It injects code at that location at runtime. That's clever. But doesn't help with your goal of loading a go plugin. SystemTap is operating at a layer beneath the Go runtime. You need something that integrates with the Go runtime.

Comment: ... thus my original question. I have all the basic research done for how to do this (spread across 15 blog posts), but I'm looking for an expert who can guide me in the safest approach to take.

Comment: What you're attempting is not supported by Go. This probably means there are no experts who can guide you, because nobody's ever done it before.

Comment: A program will only load a plugin if it is written to load a plugin. You'll have to modify and recompile the program, period.

Comment: @Karl: There's no way to do this "safely", as "safe" implies working within the language specification, which doesn't cover this use case. Most of the people who work on Go don't frequent this site, and you're more likely to find someone on the mailing list who can direct you through a specific implementation of Go's linking, calling conventions, memory layout, initialization routines, etc.

Answer (score 3):

An already built Go app does not support loading "predefined" or other plugins by default. You have to alter the app, you have to *make* it search for or expect the plugin to be loaded.

While something like this would easily be possible if the go tool would generate a binary that would look for a "default.so" plugin or a command line flag like `-autoload=pluginname`, but this is not the case.

Most libraries solve this by requiring the app to import them, which launches whatever monitoring process they desire. Which is fine for most uses.

Comment: The linux kernel includes things such as uprobe, and Go has APIs for ptrace. There are ways to inject code into a running Go process, and I'm in the process of researching how to do it, but I'd be a lot happier hearing from someone knowledgeable on the subject who can offer best practices for Go, since there are a lot of ways to go about this, ranging from live patching to trampolines to syscall interception, CPU register modification, etc.

Comment: @Karl Those seem waaaaay more harder than the hassle of having to rebuild the app with importing your lib. Unless you don't have its sources.